# How to add a row in a tableWidget PyQT?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I am currently working on a widget that was designed in Qt Designer. I am having trouble with the syntax / overall concept of trying to add a row to a Qtable in PyQT. There is no method, which I have yet found to dynamically add rows. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can add empty row and later populate all columns. This is how to insert row under all other rows:

```
rowPosition = self.table.rowCount()
table.insertRow(rowPosition)
```

after that you have empty row that you can populate like this for example( if you have 3 columns):

```
table.setItem(rowPosition , 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("text1"))
table.setItem(rowPosition , 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("text2"))
table.setItem(rowPosition , 2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("text3"))
```

You can also insert row at some other position (not necessary at the end of table)

Comment: For some reason I had to also make table.setColumnCount(3) to make the table contents visible. (might be because I am using PyQt5)

Answer (score 3):

```
def add_guest(self):
    rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
    self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)
    guest_name = self.lineEdit.text()
    guest_email = self.lineEdit_2.text()
    numcols = self.tableWidget.columnCount()
    numrows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()           
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(numrows)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(numcols)           
    self.tableWidget.setItem(numrows -1,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(guest_name))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(numrows -1,1,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(guest_email))
    print "guest added"
```

This is how i got it done for my event organisation application

Answer (score 2):

It is somewhat peculiar, I've found. To insert a row, you have to follow something similar to this:

```
tableWidget = QTableWidget()
currentRowCount = tableWidget.rowCount() #necessary even when there are no rows in the table
tableWidget.insertRow(currentRowCount, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Some text"))
```

To clarify the last line of code, the first parameter of `insertRow()` is the current row, the second one is current column (remember it's always 0-based), and the third must almost always be of type `QTableWidgetItem`).

Comment: Not working...TypeError: QTableWidget.insertRow(int): too many arguments.... Please edit the answer...

Comment: you have do like  `tableWidget.setItem(currentRowCount, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Some text"))` and **NOT** `tableWidget.insertRow(currentRowCount, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Some text"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function

```
def table_appender(widget, *args):

    def set_columns(len, pos):
        if pos == len-1:
            widget.setItem(widget.rowCount()-1, pos, QTableWidgetItem(args[pos]))
        else:
            widget.setItem(widget.rowCount()-1, pos, QTableWidgetItem(args[pos]))
            set_columns(len, pos+1)
    widget.insertRow(widget.rowCount())
    set_columns(widget.columnCount(), 0)
```